# Custom user profile data with Firebase/AppEngine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on an application where users should be able to follow their favorites users. Currently, authentication is done on the Android app via Firebase's Authentication system.

To get a reference to the current user in the Android app, I can do something like the following:

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

The `user` object only has a few methods for interacting with the user's profile, such as `.getEmail`, `.getDisplayName()`, or `.getPhotoUrl()`. However, there doesn't seem to be ways to add custom data to a user's profile.

I've also been checking out App Engine and Cloud Endpoints and plan to integrate it for various features.

What is the proper way to add custom user data, such as a list of users the current user is following, to my application?

My first though was to store references of every user in Cloud Datastore, and then store the custom data in there, however this seems like i'm duplicating functionality that should already be present in Firebase.

What is the best course of action here?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the [`getUid()` method on FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) or the [`getUid()` method on the `UserInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo) returned from `getProviderData()`.

There are two reasons for this:

1. You want to be able to distinguish between two accounts with the same display/email from different providers (e.g. Google vs Facebook).
2. For some providers, it's possible that user email addresses can change while the UID remains the same. This is true for Google accounts that are part of a domain, for example.